# Is it possible to solve for a matrix $ m $ satisfying $ m\cdot x=b $, given the vectors $ x $ and $ b $?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

At first I thought it should be `LinearSolve`, which however turns out aiming at `x`, given `m` and `b` in `m.x == b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but the solution is not unique. In some sense, the optimal solution is the following rank-one matrix:

```
m = KroneckerProduct[b, x/x.x]
```